# Android webservice call throws exception

Tags: android, web-services, android-manifest

I am developing an android application using ksoap2 web services. The web service call working fine If I set

`android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:targetSdkVersion="8"` in Manifest file.

But my application should needs

`android:minSdkVersion="14" and android:targetSdkVersion="16"`.

If I set like this it thrown an exception while calling a web service. what may be the problem? Can you share your suggestions?

Comment: Show your logcat & your code

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to  say without see any code, but probably you are performing the network request on the `UI Thread`. This operation was allowed until `Android 3.0`. Since `Android 3.0` the `NetworkOnMainThreadExecption` is thrown